# Matlab, vector comparison and If cycle

Tags: c++, matlab, vector

i'm new and i really need help. Here is my problem, i have 2 different vectors of the same size, such as:

```
A= [1 2 3 4 2]

B= [0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.2]
```

Now.. what i would like to do is to create a third vector D (of the same size of the previous two) filled with some specific elements of B.
In particular i would like to create a "if cycle" where i check the "i" element of A, and if it is inside a given range, i would pick the "k" element of B and put it in D.

What i managed to do is to create a cycle with just one of the vectors, and it works..

```
D=zeros(size(A))
for i=1:length(A)
    if A(i)>= 2 & A(i)<= 4
        D(i)=A(i)
    else
        D(i)=0
    end
end
```

Now I don't know how to implement the B  vector inside this cycle. I would like to check the values on A and then don't pick "i" but "k" for example:

```
if A(i)>= 2 & A(i)<= 4
    "pick B(k) (where i and k are both the second elements of A and B) and put it in D"
```

can someone help?

Comment: `"where i and k are both the second elements of A and B"` isn't very clear to me. Do you mean `i` is same as `k` for selecting elements? If not, how are `i` and `k` related? Also, what's the expected output for the given sample data?

Comment: so "i" is the index for A while "k" is the index for B, they should both move forward with the same step, so when i chek the i element (1st of A for example) and it is in the given range i will take the k element (1st of B) and put it on D (in the 1st space)...and so on.. is it clear?

Comment: it should be (for this example)

D=[0 0 0.3 0 0]

Comment: Would this work `D(A>=2 & A<=4) = B(A>=2 & A<=4)`?

Comment: yes is working! Thanks!

Comment: @GuglielmoMantero As an advice, in case you have two vectors of the same length, which you want to traverse with the same speed: use the same index. It is unnecessary and confusing to use more than one index.

Answer (score 0):

```
D=zeros(size(B));
idx = find(A>2 & A<4);
D(idx) = B(idx)
D =

   0.00000   0.00000   0.30000   0.00000   0.00000
```

Comment: While this answer may be correct, please add some explanation. Imparting the underlying logic is more important than just giving the code, because it helps the OP and other readers fix this and similar issues themselves.